# Compute the limit $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Compute the limit
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{n}{2^n}$$

Comment: I found it! Your turn!

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) and  its linked pages for ideas.

Comment: Me too, Asaf!  Hint to OP: Do not use imperative when asking a question here.  It's a violation of site etiquette.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By ratio test, $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}}{\frac{n}{2^{n}}}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{n+1}{2n}=\frac 1 2<1$.

Therefore $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac n {2^n}$ convergent.

$\displaystyle S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac n {2^n}=\frac 1 2 + \frac 2 {2^2} + \frac 3 {2^3}+...$   (i)

$2*$(i): $\displaystyle 2S=1 + \frac 2 {2} + \frac 3 {2^2}+...$ (ii)

(ii) $-$ (i): $\displaystyle S=1+\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 {2^2} +...$

Can you take it from here? (Answer: $S=2$)

p.s. This method requires just elementary skills. :)

Comment: Maybe it should be added that this works if we know that the series converges (i.e., $S\ne+\infty$).

Comment: @ Martin Sleziak: You are right, otherwise, $\infty-\infty$ is indeterminate.

Comment: If we subtract $S$ from $2S$, how can we conclude that the difference is equal to $S$ ?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Consider the power series with those coefficients, for $x=1$. Remember that we can integrate term-by-term within the convergence radius.

Comment: Ha-Ha! I was first :)

Comment: Yes, but I'm a set theorist. And I don't have to teach calculus this semester! So... jokes on someone else.

Answer (score 4):

**Hints:**
(1) $f(x)=\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ converges uniformly for $|x|\leq r$ for any $r<1$ and hence is differentiatable.
(2) $f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac1x\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n}$

Comment: **Hint:** If you use `1.` the software parses it as an ordered list (you may have to line break one more)