# Limit of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{n}{2^n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone help me to find the sum?

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{n}{2^n}}$$

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) is a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link @DavidMitra. I could now delete my answer without any loss to the site, but my picture is different. Making it CW instead.

Comment: This specific sum has been handled for example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/328299/11619). The one linked to by David is older, and more general. Closing this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
\begin{align}
S &= 1\cdot \frac{1}{2} + &2 \cdot \frac{1}{2^2} + 3 \cdot \frac{1}{2^3} + \cdots\\
\frac{1}{2}S &= &1 \cdot \frac{1}{2^2} + 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2^3} + \cdots
\end{align}

then we can get
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}S &= 1\cdot \frac{1}{2} + 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2^2} + 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2^3} + \cdots\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}=1
\end{align}

so $S = 2$.

Answer (score 5):

First observe that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$ and then differentiation and letting $x=1/2$ gives the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Split the same region to infinitely many rectangles in two different ways. The red way gives the area as the sum in question. The black way is something even easier to calculate.

[image]

[image]